# Redirección en promesa

Tags: javascript, angular

Soy nuevo en js y angular, estoy intentando realizar una redirección en un `sweetalert` cuando se de click en el botón lo redireccione a la pagina principal.

En HTML cuando se da click en el botón `enviar a cocina` salta el `sweetaler`t

```
  <div class="row mx-1">
    <div class="col-6 px-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm w-100" (click)="sendKitchen()">ENVIAR A COCINA</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 px-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100">PAGAR</button>
    </div>   </div>
```

**Components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent {

  constructor() { }

  sendKitchen():void {

    Swal.fire({
      position: 'top-end',
      icon: 'success',
      title: '¡Gracias!',
      html: 
      'tu orden a sido enviada a cocina <br><br>' +
      '<b>Orden</b> B1C2 <br><br>' +
      '<b>Mesero</b> suaberto',
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      confirmButtonText: 'Ir a menú principal',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      showCloseButton: true,

    }).then((result)=>{
      if (result.isConfirmed){
        
      }
    })
  }
}
  }
```

Al final localice que cuando se le de click al botón resuelve la promesa pero no consigo que envié a la pagina principal utilice router pero se quedaba pegado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías utilizar el `location.href = menu.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solo como recordatorio de como usar el router de angular te dejo un ejemplo, pero ¿Podrías poner mas informacion de que error te da al usar el angular router? porque debería funcionarte y en angular esa es la manera de hacerlo, te dejo el ejemplo:

Primero tenes que buscar el archivo llamado **app-routing.module.ts**, dentro de este archivo hay un arreglo de routes, debería quedar de esta forma:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'/Principal', component: PrincipalComponent}
];
```

Asumiendo que tu componente principal se llamaba **PrincilapComponent** ahí lo cambias por el nombre que tenga, y en la parte del **path** pones la ruta para ir a ese componente, esta ruta la defines tu.

Luego en tu componente donde usas el alert debes inyectar el gestor de rutas de angular de la siguiente forma en el constructor:

```
 constructor(private router:Router){
 }
```

Para luego usarlo en la promesa del alert de la siguiente forma:

```
.then((result)=>{
  if (result.isConfirmed){
       this.router.navigateByUrl("/Principal");
  }
})
```

Esto debería funcionar.